# Kotlin fuzzy matching

Tags: kotlin

This is a pseudo-follow up to [Kotlin Data Class Wildcard](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/152403/100439): taking in advice from that question I came upon a better but quite different solution to the same problem.

The problem: fuzzy matching AST nodes. All regular properties should be checked for equality normally (via `==`), but allowing any absent value to match a real value and recursing the fuzzy match down the `Node` hierarchy. The second requirement is that this does not require anything extra within the `Node`s themselves as this would be prohibitive towards adding new nodes and the fuzzy match is purely the domain of testing.

The reason for creating this is that the structure of a parsed AST can be very complex and in order to make writing tests easier, I want to be able to say "I don't care about this part of the parsed AST", and just test a portion of it.

### NodeMatching.kt

```
package nafi.grammar

import nafi.grammar.ast.Node
import nafi.grammar.ast.Position
import kotlin.reflect.memberProperties

infix fun Node.matches(that: Node): Boolean {
    if (this.javaClass != that.javaClass)
        return false
    else return this.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties
            .map { it.get(this) matches it.get(that) }
            .fold(true, Boolean::and)
}

private infix fun Position.matches(that: Position) =
        this.start == that.start &&
                (this.end == that.end || this.end == null || that.end == null)


private infix fun <T : Collection<*>> T.matches(that: T): Boolean {
    if (this.size != that.size) return false
    else return this.indices
            .map { this.elementAt(it) matches that.elementAt(it) }
            .fold(true, Boolean::and)
}

private infix fun Any?.matches(that: Any?): Boolean = when {
    this == null || that == null                   -> true
    this is Node && that is Node                   -> this matches that
    this is Position && that is Position           -> this matches that
    this is Collection<*> && that is Collection<*> -> this matches that
    else                                           -> this == that
}
```

### ASTMatcherTest.kt

```
package nafi.grammar

import nafi.grammar.ast.ConstantDefinition
import nafi.grammar.ast.IntegerLiteral
import nafi.grammar.ast.NafiFile
import nafi.grammar.ast.Position
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class ASTMatcherTest {
    fun testCompile(code: String, ast: NafiFile, expectedMatch: Boolean) {
        val parsed = NafiParserFacade.parse(code)
        assertEquals(expectedMatch, ast matches parsed,
                     "expected $ast, got $parsed, should ${if (!expectedMatch) "not " else ""}match"
        )
    }

    @Test fun passNoPosition() = testCompile(
            "constant id = 5",
            NafiFile(ConstantDefinition("id", IntegerLiteral("5"))),
            true
    )

    @Test fun failBadPosition() = testCompile(
            "constant id = 5",
            NafiFile(ConstantDefinition("id", IntegerLiteral("5", Position(10, 14)))),
            false
    )

    @Test fun passGoodPosition() = testCompile(
            "constant id = 5",
            NafiFile(ConstantDefinition("id", IntegerLiteral("5", Position(1, 14, 1, 15)), Position(1, 0))),
            true
    )
}
```

Because [Kotlin extensions are resolved statically](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically), **NodeMatching.kt** includes a definition of `matches` for two `Any?`s and does a manual virtual dispatch to the appropriate `matches` or `==`.

**Key Points**:

- `Position.matches` and `<T : Collection<*>>.matches` *can* be `inline`, but *should* they be?
- This requires data which is non-nullable in application logic to be nullable to allow fuzzy matching. Is there a way around that?
- Any kotlin-isms that would make the code more readable or kotlin-abuses that are making the code less readable

[The minimal AST Model that I'm using for testing can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/nafi-lang/NAFI-interpreter/blob/d5c32b0e97811edf423c9e2069f3e7227ccfa3df/src/main/kotlin/nafi/grammar/ast/NafiASTModel.kt) along with the rest of the project. The project is a Maven project and you can run the tests with `maven test`.